# Why are my email headers getting me spam boxed?

Tags: email, email-headers, email-spam

Can you please advise me on what is wrong with my headers that is getting them spamboxed by gmail and almost all mail providers?

Please note I changed the domain in the header for security purpose the real domain is: bounce@LDSDevotionalLetter.com

```
Delivered-To: daolhaze@gmail.com
Received: by 10.68.149.100 with SMTP id tz4csp62933pbb;
        Thu, 7 Nov 2013 13:47:04 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.182.99.231 with SMTP id et7mr8452573obb.10.1383860824010;
        Thu, 07 Nov 2013 13:47:04 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <bounce@LDSxxDevotionalLetter.com>
Received: from LDSxxDevotionalLetter.com ([142.11.193.90])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id jw1si2247886oeb.145.2013.11.07.13.47.03
        for <daolhaze@gmail.com>;
        Thu, 07 Nov 2013 13:47:03 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: temperror (google.com: error in processing during lookup of bounce@LDSxxDevotionalLetter.com: DNS timeout) client-ip=142.11.193.90;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=temperror (google.com: error in processing during lookup of bounce@LDSxxDevotionalLetter.com: DNS timeout) smtp.mail=bounce@LDSxxDevotionalLetter.com;
       dkim=neutral (bad format) header.i=postmaster@LDSxxDevotionalLetter.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=mail; d=LDSxxDevotionalLetter.com;
 h=To:Subject:Message-ID:Date:From:Reply-To:MIME-Version:List-Unsubscribe:Content-Type:Content-Transfer-Encoding; i=postmaster@LDSxxDevotionalLetter.com;
 bh=w3qzVUKLzraucgb4QEk34aV+tFk=;
 b=YFlmZmxhsyJVhgWoWYEfzeJtAOzrqdzpNs16Fx1xXUBU7FFri9CzksseCnp3iTcZRFsw+wd9zCkN
   tDM3ButEtcYeJTAlinAblJg4YqHioYSXGM+V8TvEcuLrc/Kij6jhoHaKWB/PGLbk/hxFyMYOp31O
   fImke+Hf0hxIB0JAziQ=
DomainKey-Signature: a=rsa-sha1; c=nofws; q=dns; s=mail; d=LDSxxDevotionalLetter.com;
 b=ULzVDamxcdnIZmlVZV3N5TPA9/TAu6ASjUa20ThUzAf10wAceGJ7B1Rwz/E2u1bSOXuJod5+k10y
   z/JS/iPPe02Zg59znuFTdXbOSXQgG/rfp0cNMMtS6KOyWYIi7utdTUaTNncaxGzTTa7YnMu/JsCK
   6kEecCSbVo4H4RFfMdQ=;
Received: from newlifeinsight.com (142.11.193.90) by LDSxxDevotionalLetter.com id hfg55e0001gh for <daolhaze@gmail.com>; Fri, 8 Nov 2013 00:47:03 +0300 (envelope-from <bounce@LDSxxDevotionalLetter.com>)
To: daolhaze@gmail.com
Subject: Hey man lets catch up
Message-ID: <7877bf51cbea722b4afa9fc09e4a844a@newlifeinsight.com>
Return-Path: bounce@LDSxxDevotionalLetter.com
Date: Fri, 08 Nov 2013 00:47:03 +0300
From: "Jason Owens" <info@LDSxxDevotionalLetter.com>
Reply-To: info@LDSxxDevotionalLetter.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Mailer-LID: 1
List-Unsubscribe: <http://newlifeinsight.com/unsubscribe.php?M=1&C=4fe5fde651bc8a830207eb401559c51c&L=1&N=11>
X-Mailer-RecptId: 1
X-Mailer-SID: 11
X-Mailer-Sent-By: 2
Content-Type: text/plain; format=flowed; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

David,

I've been hoping to get together with you since we met up a few months ago.
I'd like to take you out to lunch! there is a great fish taco place on
santa monica boulevard. Give me a hollar!

Thanks,
Jason
```

Comment: I am not sure what DKIM neutral means, and would having issues resolving to the bounce@ email cause the email to be spamboxed?

Comment: The sender domain, `LDSxxDevotionalLetter.com`, is failing a reverse DNS lookup, which by itself is often considered pretty spammy.

Comment: Some servers may object to the idea of a fish taco

Answer (score 1):

SpamAssassin objects to the header "X-Mailer-RecptId" - it literally penalises people for this, though Interspire uses it for bounce processing and other things.

However, X-Mailer-RecptId is used only by Interspire so it's a bit unjust that SpamAssassin is penalising Interspire users for the sins of others.

Some references:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/634387/which-e-mail-software-generates-these-spammy-mails
- https://www.warriorforum.com/email-marketing/1200354-edit-header-better-inbox-rate.html
- https://www.google.com/search?q=XM_RECPTID

You can check for yourself via https://mail-tester.com